# Sencha Cmd build error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: cmd, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I get this error when running a production build:

> [DBG] Scanning for plugins in folder: C:\Users\Jez\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io
>   [ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
>        at java.io.File.(Unknown Source)
>        at com.sencha.util.FileUtil.readFile(FileUtil.java:170)
>        at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.JsbBuilder.processBuild(JsbBuilder.java:29)
>        at com.sencha.command.build.JsbCommand.execute(JsbCommand.java:15)
>        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>        at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:174)
>        at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
>        at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:68)
>        at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:81)
>        at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:149)

Can anyone please tell me what it means and how to correct it

Sencha Touch 2.3.0
Sencha Command 4.0.0.203

Thanks

Comment: Did you run sencha app upgrade?

Comment: I downloaded and installed the latest versions of touch and cmd earlier today

Comment: And you created a new project? Or upgraded your old one?

Comment: Created a new one from command line: sencha generate app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha IO was at the location mentioned in the log. It was a JAR file. I ran it, then tried  a build again. This seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your stack trace:

```
[DBG] Scanning for plugins in folder: C:\Users\Jez\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.0.203\extensions\sencha-io
```

Does your app attempt to use Sencha IO? Because the error seems to suggest that Cmd is looking for an extension in that location... and that the package doesn't exist (the NullPointerException).

Assuming I'm right, and if you're running *sencha app build*, I would suggest removing any references to Sencha IO in your app to see if things work normally. Then you might have to correct the path to where Cmd looks for your Sencha IO package.

Answer (score 0):

I have noted that such issues when you use plugins, even I have gone through such error. So 1st make sure if you have used plugins and getting this error then place.

To the following steps:

1> Place ur plugin files inside => **C:\your_path\project_folder\touch\src\ux**

2> Now open **app.json** and write the path of plugins into its resources array, as shown below:

```
"resources": [
    "resources/images",
    "resources/icons",
    "resources/startup",
    "resources/data/",
    "resources/css/",
    "resources/fonts/",
    "touch/src/ux/Ext.ux.Multiselect.js"
    "touch/src/ux/TouchCalendar.js",        
    "touch/src/ux/TouchCalendarView.js",
    "touch/src/ux/Ext.ux.TouchCalendarEvents.js",
    "touch/src/ux/Ext.ux.TouchCalendarEventsBase.js",
    "touch/src/ux/Ext.ux.TouchCalendarMonthEvents.js"

],
```

3> Now open **sencha.cfg** from the following path **C:\your_path\project_folder.sencha\app\sencha.cfg**

add this path **${app.dir}/touch/src/ux**, as shown in code

```
app.name=SS

app.framework=touch

app.classpath=${app.dir}/app.js,${app.dir}/app,${app.dir}/touch/src/ux 

# this property specifies a comma separated list of paths containing
# resources to copy to the build directory
app.resource.paths=

app.build.dir=${workspace.build.dir}/${app.name}

app.framework.version=2.3.1.410
app.cmd.version=4.0.2.67
```

4> Now, run the command in the terminal **sencha app build** from your poject path.